# Triangle shaped ImageView with drag, scroll & zoom onTouch Android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-canvas

I've added **three different `bitmap` to one `ImageView`** as shown in picture below. But the problem is that I cannot edit it after the `Bitmap` is set to `ImageView`.
I want to **drag, scroll & zoom the individual `Bitmap` in the `ImageView`**.

[image]

My code for getting the combined `bitmap` is:

```
Bitmap setBitmapInTriangleShape(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2,
        Bitmap bitmap3) {
    /*
     * int[] values= new int[2]; mImageView.getLocationOnScreen(values);
     */
    double screenHeightAspect = 2.5;
    Bitmap drawnBitmap = null;

    bitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap1, screenWidth,
            (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect), true);
    bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, screenWidth,
            (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect), true);
    bitmap3 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap3, screenWidth,
            (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect), true);

    try {
        drawnBitmap = Bitmap
                .createBitmap(screenWidth,
                        (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect),
                        Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(drawnBitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(
                R.color.gray_divider_reg_edit_grid_1));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        Path path = new Path();
        BitmapShader bms = new BitmapShader(bitmap1, TileMode.CLAMP,
                TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setShader(bms);
        // bms.setLocalMatrix(matrix);

        // -----------------=for photo 1-----------------------------
        path.reset();
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

        path.lineTo(0, 0);
        path.lineTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.80), 0);
        // path.lineTo(0, 15);
        path.lineTo(0, (int) (screenHeight * 0.8706 / screenHeightAspect));
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        Matrix mt = new Matrix();

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, new Matrix(), null);
        // -------------------for photo 3-----------------------------
        BitmapShader bmsUo = new BitmapShader(bitmap3, TileMode.CLAMP,
                TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setShader(bmsUo);
        // bms.setLocalMatrix(matrix);

        path.reset();
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path.moveTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.80), 0);
        path.lineTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.80), 0);
        path.lineTo(screenWidth, 0);
        path.lineTo(screenWidth, (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect));
        // path.lineTo(800,800);
        path.lineTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.88),
                (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect));

        path.lineTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.50),
                (int) (screenHeight * 0.32 / screenHeightAspect));

        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        // ---------------------for photo 2-------------------------
        BitmapShader bmsUop = new BitmapShader(bitmap2, TileMode.CLAMP,
                TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setShader(bmsUop);
        // bmsUop.setLocalMatrix(matrix);
        path.reset();
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path.moveTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.50),
                (int) (screenHeight * 0.32 / screenHeightAspect));
        path.lineTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.50),
                (int) (screenHeight * 0.32 / screenHeightAspect));
        path.lineTo((int) (screenWidth * 0.88),
                (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect));
        path.lineTo(0, (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect));
        path.lineTo(0, (int) (screenHeight / screenHeightAspect * 0.8706));

        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return drawnBitmap;

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes draw this on a canvas and obtain the bitmap and then set the bitmpa to imageView

Comment: You could do that using masks and canvas:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801075/android-how-to-apply-mask-on-imageview

Comment: Can you show the sample code for drawing images in triangle shape on canvas? @Rajesh CP

Comment: @TrushitShah try below one....:)

Comment: @TrushitShah try my edit it may help you... :)

Comment: @OAEI Did you find any solution for your problem? please share it.

Comment: Hello @OAEI 
Did you find a way to do it? Would be nice to hear what your solution was.

Comment: @MindaugasSvirskas Nope. I didn't found any working solution for that. I gave up to find out any solution.

Answer (score 1):

here is a link for source example of how to mask image

https://github.com/hotveryspicy/MaskImage

ref from this question

[Masking(crop) image in frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614542/maskingcrop-image-in-frame)

**EDIT**

for individual zoom in and zoom out you want these three bitmaps in different layout (you need to make custom image view ) so try below URL that describe how to make your own custom layout (image view in triangle shape) etc.

https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Defining-Custom-Views

Comment: It is helpful...but not exactly as I want to do...I'm still working to get the exact shape of images. I'll put the code as well, when I'm done.

Comment: I've updated my question and help me if you know about the issue.