# How to work with porter duff composition

Tags: android, porter-duff

Here my requirement is: I have a bitmap and want to cutoff bitmap in to some different shapes, and later shuffled those bitmaps which are in different shapes, and asked to end-user to arrange them in order, if that happen showing success message.

**Now my question is:**

1. How to cut off bitmap in different shapes?
2. I tried porter duff composition but unable to handle?

It is like a puzzle game for enduser, he needs to drag, drop and rotate the bitmap.

Any idea please help me. Please look [this link as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294251/how-to-break-the-image-into-shattered-shapes-in-android).

Comment: yes, one comment was right: use BitmapShader

Comment: please provide any sample, by that i can understand.

Comment: http://www.google.com/m?q=bitmapshader+example&client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new