# How to make Android icon theme with mask

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, mask

I'm planning to make an Android icon theme set, but I want to be able to create a background/foreground frame mask to the loose icons so that they match the theme. How is the mask implemented? For example, if I want to make a mask of a ring of flowers as the background and a single flower as the foreground of any icon, how is that done in Android Studio?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what it is you are asking.  Perhaps this will be of some assistance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801075/android-how-to-apply-mask-on-imageview

Comment: Ah! I think that's precisely what I'm looking for. So you can do masking directly on ImageView...that's awesome. ps. sorry for the bad phrasing, as I'm still new to Android dev and I'm not very familiar with the technical terms yet.

Comment: That is okay. Hopefully this works out for you. If you do ask more questions though, I would try to do as much research as you can prior. Also if you cannot find a way to explain your issue verbally, perhaps creating some type of graphic may help as well. Anyways, best of luck!