# Android inverse shape using xml

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

Is it possible to 'invert' an Android xml shape? For example, you can easily create a shape with rounded corners - but what about a shape with a transparent element within it?

Let's say I have this image of an adorable puppy:

[image]

Is it possible to add a view that contains a transparent element in front of this (shown in green below)?

[image]

Comment: programmatically is definitely possible

Comment: this is called [masking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801075/android-how-to-apply-mask-on-imageview)