# How to Mask Text into an Imageview in Android?

Tags: android, imageview, image-masking

I have been trying to get the desired result as below but in-vain. I need to mask an imageview into text so that the imageview looks like text but still works as an imageview such that i can use zoom functionality in it.

[image]

The image should not overflow beyond the text border. I have out Glide-Transformations and some others but it didn't workout.The text is dynamic and can be replaced by any letters or words.

> **EDIT**

Here's a code snippet:

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.eagle).override(width, height).bitmapTransform(new CenterCrop(this),

new MaskTransformation(mContext, R.drawable.mask_e)).into(Imageview);
```

Comment: Can you provide the code snippets you have implemented so far?

Comment: @sept  `Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.eagle)
            .override(width, height)
            .bitmapTransform(new CenterCrop(this),
                new MaskTransformation(mContext, R.drawable.mask_e))
            .into(Imageview);`

This works but when Imageview becomes SubsamplingScaleImageView it breaks.

Answer (score -1):

To add a text to your ImageView you can do this:

```
<RelativeLayout> 
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/myImageSouce" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

PS. Only works inside a RelativeLayout

Comment: Please read the requirement carefully. It's not adding a text on an image. Its wraping an image in the shape of a text.

Comment: i have found the solution here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801075/android-how-to-apply-mask-on-imageview?rq=1

Comment: I have checked it out . But the end result should not be a combined bitmap. Please check the code snippet i have attached. It's similar to what i want.