# How to make asymetrical imageview

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-drawable

Good day, I have a question, how can I make my image view look like this.

[image]

I've tried to make this shape background in xml but nothing worked.
Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Just overlay another image which has a white triangle on the bottom and the rest is transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably suggest using a mask with your imageview and another image that is with the shape you want like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801075/android-how-to-apply-mask-on-imageview)

Or you could place a white drawable with the shape you need on top of the imageview.

Comment: ... which is exactly what I suggested in my comment.