# Mask/crop an image

Tags: dart, flutter

What is the best approach to display a cropped/masked image in Flutter?

Lets say I have one image with a mask (eg. an irregular star shape with transparent background) and the other image which I want to mask with this star, so that only the part inside the star of original image would be rendered.

I'm aiming for something like `PorterDuffXfermode` on Android (similar question here - [Android how to apply mask on ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801075/android-how-to-apply-mask-on-imageview)).

In case of simple mask shapes is going the [`RenderClipOval`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderClipOval-class.html) way a good approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would just paint it using a CustomPainter, setting the Paint.BlendMode on the Paint you pass to the method when you paint the image.

See https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawImageRect.html and https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Paint/blendMode.html and https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html.